# problem of memory leaks in iphone app

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I am getting leaks on the following code.

```
            cell.lblNoOfReplay.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"0 Replies. %@",(NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Last message on %@",[BabbleVilleAppDelegate dateByAddingHours:Babbleoffset withDate:[[arrayPMMainList objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]] objectForKey:@"datetime"]]] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@" "], CFSTR(""), kCFStringEncodingUTF8)];
```

Here i dont havent allocated any string but when i check for memory leaks there are some leaks in the above line .
Probably  it may be due to kCFAllocatorDefault ,so of someome has come across the same issues , help me out .

Regards
Mrugen

Comment: There's so much going on on that monster line of code, I suggest you break it up a bit with some interim variables. That will also help you narrow down the leak.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you have allocated a string. Core Foundation objects follow the [Create rule](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html): any object obtained via a function whose name contains either Create or Copy is owned by the caller and must be released by the caller when it’s finished using it.

Change your code to:

```
CFStringRef s = CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Last message on %@",[BabbleVilleAppDelegate dateByAddingHours:Babbleoffset withDate:[[arrayPMMainList objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]] objectForKey:@"datetime"]]] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@" "], CFSTR(""), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
cell.lblNoOfReplay.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"0 Replies. %@", (NSString *)s];
CFRelease(s);
```

Also, consider breaking that line into multiple pieces and intermediate variables. Other people that see that code, including your future self, will thank you.